# igraph for python: memory leak (?) in get_shortest_paths

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks, igraph

I have a large number of different graphs (each 8000+ nodes). In igraph (version 0.7.0) for python 2.7 I am trying to perform some calculations on shortest paths calculated from these graphs. In a loop each graph is imported in igraph and then the shortest paths are calculated. However, I have noticed that the memory used by python increases during each loop (even though new graphs are used in each loop). After a while my program crashes due to the memory being filled up. Does this indicate a memory leak in igraph? How could I best solve this problem?

This memory leak (?) can be demonstrated with the python code below:

```
import igraph as ig
import psutil, os
# Perform the operation below 100 times.
for run in range(100):
    mygraph = ig.Graph.Full(300)
    # To speed up calculations only the nodes that can be reached in 10 steps are considered for the shortest paths
    ig10neigh = mygraph.neighborhood(order = 10, mode = 'out')
    for v in range(mygraph.vcount()):
        paths = mygraph.get_shortest_paths(v, ig10neigh[v], mode = 'out', output = 'epath')
        #Here some calculations with the paths
    print psutil.Process(os.getpid()).get_memory_info()[0] / float(2 ** 20) # Print the memory use
```

When I run the above code my memory use slowly increases with from 22 MB to 100 MB.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked into this and indeed, `Graph.get_shortest_paths()` unfortunately has a memory leak that cannot be worked around easily. I have committed a [patch](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/commit/dbe0da6695c11552ea6338a519c38c86ac670e50) to the development tree that solves the issue, but unfortunately you will have to recompile the Python interface from scratch if you want to have this in your own version (or wait for the next minor release).

Comment: thank you very much for fixing this leak. Unfortunately I do not now how to compile igraph from scratch, so I will have to wait for the next release. Would it be possible to pass my graph to a subprocess and run the `for v in range(mygrapp.vcount()):` loop in the subprocess? This way the memory should be freed every time the loop is finished.